# Django Form Many Tto Many Fields segregated by Foreign keys

Tags: python, django

**models.py**

```
class FoodType(models.Model):
food_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)

class Foods(models.Model):
foods = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
food_type = models.ForeignKey(FoodType, default=1)

class FoodsChosen(AbstractTrainingCertificateDocuments):
user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, default=None)
foods = models.ManyToManyField(Foods, default=None)
```

**forms.py**

```
class FoodsForm(forms.ModelForm):
foods = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(renderer=HorizontalCheckboxRenderer), queryset=Foods.objects.filter(), error_messages={'required': 'Please do not forget to select the foods'})
class Meta:
model = FoodsChosen
fields = ('foods', )
```

**views.py**

```
foods_form = FoodsForm()
context_dict['foods_form'] = foods_form
return render(request, template, context_dict)
```

**index.html**

```
{% for x in foods_form.foods %}
<div class="col-md-6">
{{ certs }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I return a many-to-many checkbox form widget into many-to-many checkbox form categoized by foreign key on my template?

*FRUITS* 
"checkbox" apple 
"checkbox" banana 
"checkbox" mango 
 
*VEGETABLES* 
"checkbox" cabbage 
"checkbox" brocolli 
"checkbox" squash 
 
*MEAT* 
"checkbox" steak 
"checkbox" pork 
"checkbox" meat 
 
instead of: 
"checkbox" apple 
"checkbox" banana 
"checkbox" mango 
"checkbox" cabbage 
"checkbox" brocolli 
"checkbox" squash 
"checkbox" steak 
"checkbox" pork 
"checkbox" meat

Comment: At the very least you'd need to show the relevant model code.. preferably with whatever query you make in your view to make this checkbox list. Please read [ask]

Comment: Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32472485/edit) button under your question to update your question with new information.

Comment: Thank you for assisting @sayse

Answer (score 0):

your view.py is not correct

```
foods_form = FoodsForm()
if foods_form.isvalid():
     food = foods_form.cleaned_data['foods']
context_dict['foods_form'] = foods_form
context_dict['food'] = food
return render(request, template, context_dict)
```

and in index.htm

```
{% for x in food %}
<div class="col-md-6">
  {{ certs }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Not really, My models are just fine. I want something dyanmic Flitering that is why I have the **FoodType** model. Let us just say the FoodType model has the records of 'Fruits', 'Vegetable' and 'Meat'

And each Food has its own foreign key and the Food Model is related as many to many to a userprofile model

Comment: it's not really the saving or validity that I am concern of,, it's rather the html output, where as the manytomanyfields checkboxes shouldbe categorized according to their foreign keys as titles

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada can you explain little more because i did not get your question properly..

Comment: If you care to visit this:
http://deanchrisarmada.com/manship/code-snippets/prototype-frontend/application-form-3.html#step-10

On the Training and Certificates Section..
This is a many-to-many field form with checkboxes however I want it categorized according to their foreignkey which I do not know how to that on the template

Example:

Certificate of Profiency Trainings:
[List of Proficiency Trainings]

Basic Training:
[List of Basic Trainings]

Comment: @i think you should create three forms with queryset=Foods.objects.filter(food_type__food_type = "type of food")

Comment: Is there something else except for doing that manually? Because I want it to be dyanamic, let us say I'll add another category for the certificates

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada hmm...sorry i don't think there is another way...you should create checkbox form in HTML for dynamic i think..